# Full background image with text slideshow

Tags: html, jquery, css, slideshow

Consider the following mark up:

```
 <ul id="slideshow">
   <li><span>Image 01</span><img src="image1.jpg" alt=""></li>
   <li><span>Image 02</span><img src="image2.jpg" alt=""></li>
   <li><span>Image 03</span><img src="image3.jpg" alt=""></li>
   <li><span>Image 04</span><img src="image4.jpg" alt=""></li>
   <li><span>Image 05</span><img src="image5.jpg" alt=""></li>
   <li><span>Image 06</span><img src="image6.jpg" alt=""></li>
 </ul>
```

I would like the image to be full screen of the entire page and the text positioned on top. The images/text should also transition with a delay.

How can I do this with simple jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

you are using the CSS SNAP